# Can't filter dataframe inside UDF using scala

Tags: scala, dataframe

We want to filter a dataframe based on values of other dataframe row. The filtering of dataframe is performed inside udf which is not actually happening. Even if we try to show the dataframe `(df.show())`, either the server does not stop or we get the output.

```
main()
{
    val x = udf(y_) 
    val df1 = //read from source file1
    val df2 = //read from source file2
    df1.select(x(df1(col1)))
}

y(col1 : String) : String{
    val output = df2.filter(df2(col1)===col1).select(df2(col2)).first().get(0).toString()
    return output
}
```

**Sample input:**

```
  Dataframe1:

  |PERSON_SK|         STATE|          ADDRESS1|
  |---------|--------------|------------------|
  |   111101|      Delaware|3020 Ode Turner Rd|
  |    11111|       Alabama| 2136 Pine Tree Ln|  
  |   211111|       mexico |3320 Burke Mill Rd|


  Dataframe2:

  |PERSON_SK|         STATE|          ADDRESS1|  city code|
  |---------|--------------|------------------|-----------|
  |         |      Delaware|3020 Ode Turner Rd|      62410|
  |         |       Alabama| 2136 Pine Tree Ln|      64128|
```

**Sample output:**
(Want to update the matched `person_sk` data to the column in the dataframe2, without using join). By using filter condition.

```
  |PERSON_SK|         STATE|          ADDRESS1|  city code|
  |---------|--------------|------------------|-----------|
  |   111101|      Delaware|3020 Ode Turner Rd|      62410|
  |   11111 |       Alabama| 2136 Pine Tree Ln|      64128|
```

Comment: The use of dataframe/RDD data inside other dataframe/RDDs operations is not supported by spark's execution model. So that's a big no. To get more help, I suggest you edit your question to add a sample example of your input and expected output. There is probably a way to do what you want by either joining/grouping the dataframes and/or precomputing partial result.

Answer (score 0):

Common approach to the problem is to use [`join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@join(right:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],joinExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) instead of user defined function

```
val df1 = //
val df2 = //
val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1(col1) === df2(col1)) // joins dataframes by values in col1 column
val df = df3.select(df2(col2)) // gets only needed column from the join
df.show()
```

Comment: can u be much brief in your answer without using join condition.

Comment: without join you will need to fetch all data from one dataframe to the driver. It breaks the purpose of spark - to work with data that does not fit on single machine. If you can afford to fetch data from dataframe to the driver then you don't need spark